# Facebook pixel test_event_code

Tags: javascript, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-pixel

Ive been looking across the documentation for meta's pixel and I can't seem to find much on where to place the test_event_code https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api/parameters/main-body#test_event_code in conjunction with `fbq()`

Is it in the fourth parameter? because theres very little I've found on it.

Javascript:

`fbq('track', 'lead', data, {eventID: 'EVENT_ID', test_event_code: 'CODE'})`

Answer (score 0):

In the "Test events" tab of your Pixel on the Business Account Manager you would find the following instructions

> Test server events
> Follow these steps on your terminal or [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=POST&path=722541572765506%2Fevents&data=%5B%7B%22action_source%22%3A%22website%22%2C%22event_id%22%3A12345%2C%22event_name%22%3A%22TestEvent%22%2C%22event_time%22%3A1676649087%2C%22user_data%22%3A%7B%22client_user_agent%22%3A%22Mozilla%2F5.0%20(iPhone%3B%20CPU%20iPhone%20OS%2013_3_1%20like%20Mac%20OS%20X)%20AppleWebKit%2F605.1.15%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Version%2F13.0.5%20Mobile%2F15E148%20Safari%2F604.1%22%2C%22em%22%3A%22f660ab912ec121d1b1e928a0bb4bc61b15f5ad44d5efdc4e1c92a25e99b8e44a%22%7D%7D%5D&test_event_code=TEST93608) to start seeing activity.
>
> 1. Within your server payload, add the "test_event_code" parameter to the event you wish to test.
>    TEST93608
> 2. Copy the test code and paste it below as the value of your test_event_code parameter. For example: {test_event_code: TEST93608}
> 3. Send the payload. If the payload is received successfully, it will be shown on this screen.

In Java, using the FB sdk that would mean

```
import com.facebook.ads.sdk.serverside.EventRequest;
...
EventRequest myEventRequest = new EventRequest(this.pixelId, this.context);
myEventRequest.addDataItem(myEvent).setTestEventCode("TEST93608");
```